# Why doesn't the c# compiler issue an error when a non nullable type is compared with null?

Tags: c#

The following code compiles:

```
ulong x=0;
if (x==null) throw ArgumentNullException();
```

Why would x==null be permitted if x is a non nullable type?

Comment: You do get a warning: "warning CS0472: The result of the expression is always 'false' since a value of type 'ulong' is never equal to 'null' of type 'ulong?'". [See here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEUCuA7AHwAEAmARgFgAoanAGwjwHMACBAXgAYBua6gSwBmLABQd2eenQCULDAAsoEAO4s8MVQEEoTHAFsYeDADkpAUQRgYABwz9GI6dyA===)

Comment: You can tell Visual Studio to treat warnings as errors in a solution, if you like.

Comment: BTW, This is one more reason why you should use `is null` and `is not null` (or, prior to c# 9, `is object`) to check for nullablility. For more information, read my blog post entitled [The perfect non-null test](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2019/11/13/the-perfect-non-null-test/) and it's follow up [c#9 is finally here (this is not about init-only or records](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2020/11/15/c9-is-finally-here-this-is-not-about-init-only-or-records/)

Comment: Ahhh - thanks. Operator overloading - insert facepalm emoji here -  Thanks folks